# Get sum of events in one day

Tags: r, sum, frequency

I have a dataset like the one shown below (15 years of data) of half hourly interval data and the occurrence of an event (1 meaning it happened and 0 that it did not)

```
Date                    Event
2002-04-27 19:30:00      0
2002-04-27 20:00:00      0
2002-04-27 20:30:00      0
2002-04-27 21:00:00      0
2002-04-27 21:30:00      1
2002-04-27 22:00:00      1
2002-04-27 22:30:00      0
2002-04-27 23:00:00      0
2002-04-27 23:30:00      1
2002-04-28 00:00:00      1
2002-04-28 00:30:00      1
2002-04-28 01:00:00      1
2002-04-28 01:30:00      0
2002-04-28 02:00:00      0
2002-04-28 02:30:00      0
2002-04-28 03:00:00      0
2002-04-28 03:30:00      0
2002-04-28 04:00:00      0
2002-04-28 04:30:00      0
2002-04-28 05:00:00      0
2002-04-28 05:30:00      0
2002-04-28 06:00:00      0
2002-04-28 06:30:00      0
2002-04-28 07:00:00      0
```

What I would like to do is to calculate for each day  (e.g `2002-04-27`) the number of events that occurred. However, consecutive 1's mean that it is just one event and also 1's crossing a day, say for example `2002-04-27 21:30:00` has a 1, and so is `2002-04-28 00:00:00` but that would be considered as 1 event only that occurred on the `2002-04-27`. An output like something below would be ideal.

```
Date           No_Event
2002-04-27       2
2002-04-28       0
```

So, how would I go about doing this? Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify the issue of the consecutive 1's? Your example output shows 2 events for the 28th, but your explanation suggests there would be 0.

Comment: The `29th` would suggest `0` as well.

Comment: @DominicComtois Sorry, I should have mentioned that the output I presented above is just an example of how I would like it to be and the values of 1's and 0's is just a subset from a bigger dataset.

Comment: You should include the actual result for your toy dataset.

Comment: @JasonJB tnx, Now it is less ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `lubridate`(for group by day) and `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
setDT(df)
df[Event!=shift(Event, fill=0), sum(Event), by=floor_date(Date, unit="day")]

#   floor_date V1
#1: 2002-04-27  2
#2: 2002-04-28  0
```

---

`df` used in above example

```
 df <- data.frame(Date=seq(as.POSIXct("2002-04-27 19:30:00 ", tz="GMT"), as.POSIXct("2002-04-28 07:00:00 ", tz="GMT"), by="30 min"),
                     Event=c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L))
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the 28th should have 0 events as it's the continuation of the 27th's event.

Comment: I mean the event on 2002-04-27 23:30:00 should be counted on the 27th but all consecutive 1's should be filtered out

Comment: I see. But OPs desired result suggests something quite different.

Comment: Yeah I asked for clarification.

Comment: @ExperimenteR I have loaded both `lubridate` and `data.table` but still get the error below when I run the code

`Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "shift"`

Comment: It requires dev version from github.

Comment: Or load dplyr and use `lag(Event)` instead of shift. Or you just might as well use dplyr as `df%>%filter(Event!=lag(Event))%>%group_by(floor)%>%summarise(sum(Event))`

Comment: If we change the first Event to 1, i.e. `df$Event[1] <- 1`, then it still gives 2 events on the first day but it should give 3.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck You're right. Thanks for pointing out anomaly. Remedy is given.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few different ways to do it:

**1) base** Here is a base solution.  First we create a logical vector which is TRUE if the current event is 1 and the prior event is 0 (which occurs when diff == 1) and then we sum it by Date:

```
No_Events <- tapply(diff(c(0, df$Event)) == 1, as.Date(df$Date), sum)
```

giving:

```
> No_Events
2002-04-27 2002-04-28 
         2          0
```

If its important that the output be a data frame then try `as.data.frame(No_Events)` or `data.frame(Date = as.Date(names(No_Events)), No_Event = unname(No_Events))` .

**1a)** Here is a variation using `aggregate` instead of `tapply` where we first create a data frame `tr` that contains a `Date` column with just dates and a `No_Event` column marking any 1 not preceeded by a 1.  Then we perform the `aggregate`:

```
tr <- transform(df, No_Event = diff(c(0, df$Event)) == 1, Date = as.Date(Date))
aggregate(No_Event ~ Date, tr, sum)
```

giving:

```
        Date No_Event
1 2002-04-27        2
2 2002-04-28        0
```

**2) zoo** Here is a zoo solution.  Read the data frame into a zoo object, merge it with a diff==1 column filling appropriately and `aggregate`:

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(df, tz = "")
m <- merge(z, No_Event = diff(z) == 1, fill = coredata(z[1]))
z.ag <- aggregate(m, as.Date(format(time(z))), sum)
```

giving:

```
> z.ag
           z No_Event
2002-04-27 3        2
2002-04-28 3        0
```

Ignore the `z` column or remove it via `z.ag[, -1]` or via `z.ag[, -1, drop = FALSE]` .

Answer (score 1):

First make a "day" column

```
dat$day <- strftime(x = dat$Date, format = "%D") # try %F as well
```

Find consecutive 1's and keep only the first

```
for(i in nrow(dat):2) {
  if(dat$Event[i]==1 && dat$Event[i-1]==1)
      dat$Event[i] <- 0
}
```

Then agregate the results

```
by(data = dat$Event, INDICES = dat$day, FUN = sum)

dat$day: 04/27/02
[1] 2
-----------------------------------------------------------------
dat$day: 04/28/02
[1] 0
```

Comment: Would there be a problem in your `for` loop?  For instance, if dat$Event[1]  ==1 and dat$Event[2]==1, then you set dat$Event[2] = 0, but then on the next iteration if dat$Event[3] == 1 it would be passed on.

Comment: Oh yeah I assumed only 2 consecutive 1's would occur. Let me fix this.

Comment: Done. Used a loop from the bottom up this time.